# MySQL syntax error...don't understand why

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm very very new to MySQL/SQL. I'm trying to create a database with a couple of tables. The first few tables created just fine, but this last one is giving me trouble. Here's what I am doing:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE Order (                                                    
-> CustomerId INTEGER NOT NULL,                                                 
-> EmployeeId INTEGER,
-> Id INTEGER,
-> DT DATETIME(),
-> PRIMARY KEY (Id),
-> );
```

I am presented with this error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Order (
CustomerId INTEGER NOT NULL,
EmployeeId INTEGE' at line 1
```

Any ideas?

Thank you :)

Comment: `ORDER` is a reserved keyword. Maybe use another name `Orders`?

Comment: @DhruvSaxena Oh my goodness >.< Thank you so so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Take the , off the end:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE Order (                                                    
-> CustomerId INTEGER NOT NULL,                                                 
-> EmployeeId INTEGER,
-> Id INTEGER,
-> DT DATETIME(),
-> PRIMARY KEY (Id)
-> );
```